# What are some common ways that smart quotes will be incorrectly encoded?

Tags: unicode, encoding

Smart quotes cause problems when they are saved in one encoding and then rendered/viewed using a different encoding. What are some ways that smart quotes will appear when rendered incorrectly?

I'm trying to solve the problem where you see an incorrect character encoding and can then say, "Oh, those should be smart quotes."

Comment: Why not try it and find out? Create a string with smart quotes and save it with the correct encoding. Read it in assuming incorrect encodings. See what you get. Do that as many ways as you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common encoding mixup is probably UTF-8 versus ANSI/Latin1.

The ANSI/Latin1 encoding of “ ‘ ’ ” is [93] [91] [92] [94] hexadecimal. If interpreted as UTF-8, these bytes will most likely be treated as invalid characters and may appear as boxed question marks.

The UTF-8 encoding of “ ‘ ’ ” is [E2 80 9C] [E2 80 98] [E2 80 99] [E2 80 9D] hexadecimal. If interpreted as ANSI/Latin1, these bytes will appear as â€œ â€˜ â€™ â€.

Comment: You are highly mistaken.  Latin-1 is a legal alias for ISO 8859-1. And CP1252 is not ISO 8859-1.  Don’t believe Microsoft’s lies.

Comment: Latin1 (ISO-8859-1) doesn't have smart quotes. In general, all ISO-8859-* character sets reserve the 0x80-0x9F range for the C1 control codes. Windows's CP1252 is not a legal standard, it's just a bastardized version of ISO-8859-1 with the C1 range changed, so it's ANSI as in "loosely based in ISO, of which ANSI is the north-american representative, all coincidence with reality is purely accidental".